# Auth error: Unable to lookup user record

Tags: windows, mac-osx, dovecot, outlook, mac-osx-server

I have notice at mail-err.log that sometimes i get this error for a windows 7 user (that IP belongs to the client, if add more accounts there i will receive more of this errors for each account user):

```
auth: Error: od(teste2,192.168.1.83,<WxTcCg9CJADAqAFT>): validate response: unable to lookup user record
```

My server is a MacosX with Server app3, and as a client i am using a windows 7 with outlook 2013.

All seems to be working fine.

Comment: Is the user in the group "Workgroup"? and also the od stands for Open Directory right?  Maybe that helps it start ringing bells and figuring it out....

Comment: I didnt had my users at  Workgroup that came by default but i have add that group to all users and same result. I was using just one group for mail services that i have created. And i am using Open Directory where all clients connect through dovecot and send with postfix.

Comment: Is the IP address shown coming from the client or the server?  If it is the server, you might have open directory configuration issues, since it should be referred to from the fqdn not the address usually.  I'll have to compare some similar logs to help further though,

Comment: That IP belongs to the client